# how to extract a part of header in Fasta file by using Linux command

Tags: regex, linux, vim

I have a Fasta file with unique header,I would like to extract a part of this header by using Regular expression in Unix.

for example My Fasta file start with this header:

```
>jgi|Penbr2|47586|fgenesh1_pm.1_#_25
```

and I would like to extract just the last part of this header like:

```
>fgenesh1_pm.1_#_25
```

Actually I use this regular expression in vim editor but It did not work:

```
:%s/^([^|]+\|){3}//g
```

or

```
:%s/^([A-Z][0-9]+\|){3}//g
```

I would be appropriate if give me some suggestion.

Comment: Try `s/^\([^|]*|\)\+//g`.

Comment: I tried this command as well but it could not find the pattern

Answer (score 3):

You can use `sed`:

```
sed -e 's/>.*|/>/' fasta-file
```

i.e. everything between `>` and `|` is replaced by `>`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if the leading `>` is also a part of your text. Assume that they are not.

Since you tagged with `vim`, then I just post the vim solution.

You can make the usage of the "greedy" of regex:

In vim:

```
%s/.*|//
```

will leave the last part, this is the easiest way.

in vim you can use `\zs, \ze` and `non-greedy` matching too:

```
%s/\zs.\{-}\ze[^|]\+$//
```

Of course, if you like grouping, you can use `\(...\)` to group and don't use `\zs \ze`.

In your codes, you grouped just with `(...)` without escaping. I don't know how did you configure your `magic` setting in your vimrc, if you use default, you have to escape the `( and )` to give them special meanings (grouping here). Just like what we do with BRE. Do a `:h magic`, and find the table to know the difference.

In vim do `:h terms` to get detail information.